# Understanding a simple multiprocessing script

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to understand how Python's multiprocessing module work. To do so, a made a very simple version of the code I'm working on and tried to make it work in parallel. According to what I read, using a `pool` would be better suited to my program than using `mp.Process`.

Below is what I came up with:

```
import time, os
import multiprocessing as mp

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, ID):
        self.ID = ID

    def showID(self):
        for k in range(0,4):
            print('Foo #', self.ID, '\tID:', os.getpid(), '\tParent ID:', os.getppid())
            time.sleep(0.2)

# MAIN
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())
    print(' ')

    foos = [Foo(2), Foo(3)]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)

    # Code below doesn't work
    pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID, ())
    pool.apply_async(foos[1].showID, ())
```

The list `foos` will eventually contain between 10 and 20 objects. The method `Foo.showID` will also eventually return something. My goal would be to send as many tasks (`foos` members) when it's time for them to run so they can be dispatched to one of the `pool`'s processes.

If I run the code above, nothing happens, ie. only `parent process` and `process id` at the beginning are displayed. If I replace the two last lines by:

```
pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID())
pool.apply_async(foos[1].showID())
```

both of them are executed in the main process one after the other:

```
parent process: 3380
process id: 6556

Foo # 2         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 3         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 3         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 3         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 3         ID: 6556        Parent ID: 3380
```

Finally, if I replace them with something like this:

```
pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID, ())
pool.apply_async(foos[1].showID())
```

I get the expected behavior (I think):

```
parent process: 3380
process id: 4772

Foo # 3         ID: 4772        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6364        Parent ID: 4772
Foo # 3         ID: 4772        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6364        Parent ID: 4772
Foo # 3         ID: 4772        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6364        Parent ID: 4772
Foo # 3         ID: 4772        Parent ID: 3380
Foo # 2         ID: 6364        Parent ID: 4772
```

What is happening here? I noticed the same behavior if I try to use a function that is not defined inside the `Foo` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[apply_async](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async) receives a function

When you use `foos[0].showID` without the parenthesis you're passing the function, and not calling it, but when doing

```
pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID())
```

You're first evaluating `foos[0].showID()`, then passing its return value as an argument to `apply_async`. The one that ends up doing the evaluation is the caller of `apply_async` and that's synchronous processing.

It's equivalent to doing:

```
foos[0].showID()
pool.apply_async()
foos[1].showID()
pool.apply_async()
```

Your first try fails because you're not waiting for the async calls to execute. After calling.

```
pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID, ())
pool.apply_async(foos[1].showID, ())
```

Your program quits so you don't wait for the output.

Finally

```
pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID, ())
pool.apply_async(foos[1].showID())
```

Is equivalent to:

```
pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID, ())
foos[1].showID()
```

Makes one async call and one sync call, so it sort of works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is that you didn't wait for the child processes to do the work. You scheduled the work items and exited causing the pool killed the workers. Keep the result objects returned when you schedule the job and wait for them to complete.

```
import time, os
import multiprocessing as mp

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, ID):
        self.ID = ID

    def showID(self):
        for k in range(0,4):
            print('Foo #', self.ID, '\tID:', os.getpid(), '\tParent ID:', os.getppid())
            time.sleep(0.2)

# MAIN
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())
    print(' ')

    foos = [Foo(2), Foo(3)]

    pool = mp.Pool(processes=2)

    results = []
    results.append(pool.apply_async(foos[0].showID, ()))
    results.append(pool.apply_async(foos[1].showID, ()))

    for result in results:
        result.wait()
```

Comment: I had to accept one answer only, but this answer was helpful too since it also shows how to retrieve the results. Thanks!